# How I can create and remove a network drive from Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, network-drive, mapped-drive

I'm writing a Inno Setup script which need to execute a very old third party setup application, this old installer (called setup.exe) only works from a root folder (if not fails), so I need to create (and remove) a network drive to copy the files of this installer and then execute the setup.exe. so the question is how i can create and remove network drive from Inno Setup? I am looking something like the  [`WNetAddConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnectiona) function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`WshNetwork`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/s6wt333f(v=vs.85)) object, which is part of the [`Windows Script Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/f51wc7hz(v=vs.85)):

```pascal
var
  WshNetWork : Variant;
begin
  WshNetWork:=CreateOleObject('WScript.Network');
  //create the network drive
  WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive('H:', '\\localhost\c$\data');

  //do your stuff here

  //remove the network drive
  WshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive('H:');
end;
```